# Citation keys in PDF, unprocessed references: TexStudio, biblatex-chicago

Tags: compiling, texstudio, biblatex-chicago

I'm using TexStudio and the biblatex-chicago package to write a humanities thesis and am having problems getting my PDF to show my full citations as footnotes and to print the bibliography.  I have read the documentation and understand the peculiarities of the compiling/building sequence I need to use for Tex Studio.  I have also read posts related to my question but so far have not been able to identify a solution that works for me.  I was wondering if some of my other packages are interfering or if I'm just overlooking something simple.   I'm looking for someone to please point me in the right direction.  I'm also happy to be made aware of any other errors you can spot in my preamble.

My MWE (please let me know if you need more details):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright,draft]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}    
\usepackage{parskip}    
\doublespacing    
\usepackage{hyperref}    
\usepackage{comment}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\usepackage{url}    
\usepackage{microtype}    
\usepackage{color}    
\usepackage{nth}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\pagestyle{fancy}    
\usepackage[nowatermark]{fixmetodonotes}

\usepackage[style=long,nonumberlist,toc,xindy,acronym,nopostdot]{glossaries}


\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\makeglossary

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}    
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\addbibresource{C:/Users/annas/Documents/introbib}



\begin{document}

some text\autocite{azari2008} more text\autocite{beate2012} 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

My (sample) introbib.bib file looks like this:

```
@Article{azari2008,
  author   = {Azari, Jaz},
  title    = {Review Essay},
  journal  = {Small Wars \& Insurgencies},
  year     = {2008},
  volume   = {19},
  number   = {2},
  pages    = {274--281},
}

@Article{beate2012,
  author   = {Beate, Jahn},
  title    = {Humanitarian Intervention},
  journal  = {International Politics},
  year     = {2012},
  volume   = {49},
  pages    = {36--58},
}
```

I don't receive any error messages as such, just this comment: `\name` is deprecated in sorting specifications, please use `\field`, which I don't understand.

Comment: You are missing the extension .bib: `\addbibresource{C:/Users/annas/Documents/introbib.bib}` (and I wouldn't use absolute pathes. Put the bib either in a texmf-tree or in the folder of your document).

Comment: Thanks. I plugged the code into Sharlatex (feeling a bit silly that I hadn't tried this earlier) and it seems to have worked. I think the absolute paths bit makes a difference.

Comment: I see the same message. I believe `biblatex` has been updated since the most recent `biblatex-chicago` update, so that `biblatex-chicago` is still using commands that have been changed in `biblatex`. I would imagine future updates will fix this. It's just a warning message, so you can ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

The current [`biblatex-chicago`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) version 1.0rc1 dated 2016-06-07 indeed spits out warnings of the form

```
Package biblatex Warning: '\name' is deprecated in sorting specifications, please use '\field'.

Package biblatex Warning: '\list' is deprecated in sorting specifications, please use '\field'.
```

Even in the minimal example

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You can safely ignore these warnings, `biblatex` just issues a warning and uses the correct command (`\field`) internally. The package author should probably be notified so he can correct the sorting scheme definition.

It turns out the backwards compatibility code was added with [this commit](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/e7294fe7adaccd9361f1ac913de4c997e3d6675d) and so the warnings only surface starting with version 3.5 of `biblatex`. I can't test, but I assume with previous versions things probably failed silently.